# LibGDX getRotationMatrix in landscape

Tags: camera, libgdx, rotation, device

I want to rotate my Libgdx Perspective Camera like the device, so that I can put 3d Objects on specific points in my room and when I rotate my device my perspective camera should do the same.

I found this code in the internet:

```
        //update camera rotation
    //get rotation matrix
    Matrix4 mat4 = new Matrix4();
    Gdx.input.getRotationMatrix(mat4.val);

    //set new rotation
    camera.up.set(mat4.val[Matrix4.M11], mat4.val[Matrix4.M12], mat4.val[Matrix4.M10]);
    camera.direction.set(-mat4.val[Matrix4.M21], -mat4.val[Matrix4.M22], -mat4.val[Matrix4.M20]);

    camera.update();
```

Andthis seems to work with portrait mode, but I use landscape mode. Does anyone know how to rotate the matrix correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

Hm... I use the same code, my world has y up. However it does not work in portrait mode, but only in landscape mode.

I'd also like to know how to get that working in portrait mode. Of course, it would be best if it would not matter if I hold the phone in portrait or landscape mode or even in a 45° angle. Is this possible ?